# Naming convention for interface to access one field

Tags: java, naming-conventions

My classes share several fields and accessors. For example
`getId()` and `setId(Long id)`

and
`getTimestamp()` and `setTimestamp(Instant time)`

I want to abstract these methods in separate interfaces. I am looking for a best practice to name these interfaces

I suppose possible propositions are:

`HasId` or `WithId` or `Timestamped` (but this does not work with ID, as you cannot be `Ided`)

Is there a standard naming convention for these interfaces?

Comment: Identifiable, Timestampable?

Comment: If you can't think of a good name for it the that's a sign that the design could be _too_ abstracted.

Comment: Take `Serializable` for example. But this is opinion-based ... not sure they are any "good" answer.

Comment: Wondering if you really need that abstraction. What are you hoping to accomplish with this abstraction? Note that it might be a good idea for some fields/accessors, but you could end up with something like: `class Something implements HasId, HasTimestamp, HasName, HasList, HasMoreThanYouThink, Serializable` ;-) and `HasMoreThanYouThink` may even extend other interfaces as well :-) But some are probably fine... Use the naming which fits your purpose the most. The naming you feel the most comfortable with.

Comment: FYI Spring uses *Aware, like in `ApplicationContextAware` for setters

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any best practice here, as it depends on what the use case is. Remember an interface is a "contract", so when naming them think about them as that, contracts.

In your example (id) I've seen people using "IsIdentified", "Identified", "Identifiable", "WithIdentifier"... None of them is wrong really, but I prefer to use the "-able" suffix.

Now don't take that as "all interfaces should have the -able suffix". Whatever makes your code clearer and the purpose of the interface self explanatory :)